# Mass replace deprecated functions in entire projects

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of PHP coded websites that have been recently moved to a PHP 5.4 server and they're throwing deprecation warnings and errors.

Is there a way to mass find & replace function names with the proper ones? For example, I would like to be able to replace all instances of session_unregister('someVar') with unset($_SESSION['someVar'])...

Should i use regex or is there an other way?

Comment: Any such search-and-replace would happen outside of PHP, using whatever tools are available in your operating system. PHP is completely unrelated, you're just looking for how to perform mass search-and-replace on text files.

Comment: Not all deprecated functions have the same arguments/signature to that of their counterpart.

Comment: One thought is implement your own session_unregister in your own namespace...

Comment: If you use an IDE such as NetBeans, there's usually a Refactoring tool that you can use. Regex search and replace works for most simple situations.

Comment: All comments are correct, i'm not looking to do this from inside my  PHP code but with my code editor. Doug, i'll give your suggestion a shot, sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example you could use `sed` like this:

```
echo "session_unregister('someVar')" | sed 's/session_unregister(/unset\($_SESSION[/;s/)/])/'
```

A bit more flexible would be to use the C preprocessor. Assume your php source file name is `my.php`. Add extension `.h` so it becomes `my.php.h`. At the beginning of the file, insert:

```
#define session_unregister(X) unset($_SESSION[X])
```

Assume the file contains lines like in your example: `session_unregister('someVar')`

Run the preprocessor like this:

```
cc -E my.php.h
```

Now you should instead see `unset($_SESSION['someVar'])`
(plus some extra garbage you don't want).

Note that this just answers your particular question, but I wouldn't recommend it without more detailed testing.